# Data doesn't display on page load in VueJS app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select drop-down which displays the data either alphabetically or by relevance. It works okay but the issue I have is the data doesn't display when the page loads. It only displays after I have made a selection on the drop-down menu.

I tried adding variations of'this.sortItems();' this.sortatoz();and  to mounted but this did not help.

What am I missing?

```
<select v-model="sortatoz" @change="sortItems">
    <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="alphabetically">Alphabetically</option>
    <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
  </select>

         <div v-for="element in copiedList" :key="element">
          <div>{{ element }}</div>
          </div>
```

Computed:

```
sortItems() {
      if (this.sortatoz === "alphabetically") {
        this.copiedList = [...this.list].sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1));
      } else {
        if (this.sortatoz === "relevance") {
          this.copiedList = [...this.list];
        }
      }
    },

 return {
      list: ["A", "C", "B"],
      copiedList: [],
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `this. copiedList `?

Comment: You're probably trying to do that before `this.list` is populated

Comment: @popnoodles How would I address that?

Comment: Show us in the question how `this.list` is populated, and when

Comment: I have added this in to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuejs computed property are made to `return` a property and then access this property from the dom ([see this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html))

Here, you can return a new list from the computed property and show this list from the template.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: () => ({
    list: ["A", "C", "B"],
    copiedList: [],
    sortatoz: "alphabeticallyAsc"
  }),

  computed: {
    sortedItems() {
      if (this.sortatoz === "alphabeticallyAsc") {
        return [...this.list].sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1));
      } else if (this.sortatoz === "alphabeticallyDesc") {
        return [...this.list].sort((a, b) => (a < b ? 1 : -1));
      } else {
        if (this.sortatoz === "relevance") {
          return [...this.list];
        }
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <select v-model="sortatoz">
    <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="alphabeticallyAsc">Alphabetically ASC</option>
    <option value="alphabeticallyDesc">Alphabetically DESC</option>
    <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
  </select>

  <div v-for="element in sortedItems" :key="element">
    <div>{{ element }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note : You could also have made another list and update this list `onchange as you did`.

You can update the list in the mounted by setting the default value of the sort and triggering the `sortItems` functions or more simply by making a copy of the array.

Here is an example of this implementation :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: () => ({
    list: ["A", "C", "B"],
    copiedList: [],
    sortatoz: ""
  }),
  
  mounted(){
    this.copiedList = [...this.list]
  },

  methods: {
    sortItems() {
      if (this.sortatoz === "alphabeticallyAsc") {
        this.copiedList = [...this.list].sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1));
      } else if (this.sortatoz === "alphabeticallyDesc") {
        this.copiedList = [...this.list].sort((a, b) => (a < b ? 1 : -1));
      } else {
        if (this.sortatoz === "relevance") {
          this.copiedList = [...this.list];
        }
      }
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <select v-model="sortatoz"  @change="sortItems">
    <option disabled value="" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="alphabeticallyAsc">Alphabetically ASC</option>
    <option value="alphabeticallyDesc">Alphabetically DESC</option>
    <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
  </select>

  <div v-for="element in copiedList" :key="element">
    <div>{{ element }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @RenaudC5. This is a very comprehensive answer!